# Which Content Types to Inherit from for Publishing Pages

Tags: content-type, page-layout

I would like to create some Custom Content Types to be used in some custom page Layouts.  I am a bit confused as to which Parent Content Type to Inherit from.  There are "Page Layout Content Types" (Article and Welcome), and there are Publishing Content Types (Page and Page Layout).

This seems confusing, are there any guidelines?

Bismarck

Answer (score 0):

Welcome and Article content types are some 'Out of the Box' custom page content types. They inherit from the Page Publishing Content Type. 
You can use the Welcome and Article ones for customization, they contain some fields you can reuse.

When these available fields are not needed, you can inherit from the Page content type (with ContentTypeID 0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39). See the MSDN doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648024.aspx for fields and content type definitions.

For Page Layouts you generally do not need a custom content type. You need to create a page layout instance instead.